# HTTP status code always returning 200 from HttpServletResponse

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm using Spring AOP Aspect class to log request and response.

Below is my code

```
@AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(* com.tr.dco.fp.ipam.controller..*.*(..))", returning = "retVal")
public void logAfter(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object retVal) {
    HttpServletResponse response = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getResponse();
}
```

Here, on successful response, I am always getting 200 status code even though the status code is 201 or any other.

Answer (score 1):

Adding plain AspectJ aspect afer controller method is a bad idea. There are other pieces of Spring Web framework that can change the web response e.g. result code might be set with [`@ResponseStatus`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ResponseStatus.html) annotation.

You have to become part of the Spring Web processing logic e.g. by registering a [`HandlerInterceptorAdapter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/HandlerInterceptorAdapter.html). Take a look at [Spring - Modify response headers after controller processing](https://mtyurt.net/post/spring-modify-response-headers-after-processing.html) to see how to do it.

Alternatively you can write a JavaEE filter before Spring's `DispatcherServlet`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it this way:

```
  @AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(* com.tr.dco.fp.ipam.controller..*.*(..))", returning = "result")
  public void afterReturning(final JoinPoint joinPoint, final ResponseEntity<?> result) {

    data.put("status_code", result.getStatusCodeValue());
  }
```